# RStudio copy/paste file path from file not working

Tags: r, rstudio

I recently downloaded RStudio version 1.2.1555 (preview version) to solve another issue (which was solved by the update), but have since been unable to paste the file path of a file copied in windows explorer (as in Ctrl C while the file I want is highlighted) into the script editor. Instead of pasting, nothing happens. I have tried copy/paste from other applications, such as word and firefox, and within RStudio, and all other copy and pasting seems to be working. Version info below:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)
> RStudio.Version()
$citation

To cite RStudio in publications use:

  RStudio Team (2019). RStudio: Integrated Development for R. RStudio, Inc., Boston, MA URL http://www.rstudio.com/.

A BibTeX entry for LaTeX users is

  @Manual{,
    title = {RStudio: Integrated Development Environment for R},
    author = {{RStudio Team}},
    organization = {RStudio, Inc.},
    address = {Boston, MA},
    year = {2019},
    url = {http://www.rstudio.com/},
  }


$mode
[1] "desktop"

$version
[1] ‘1.2.1555’
```

Any ideas on what might be the problem/how to fix this?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're doing. Can you step through what you do? For instance, from file explorer, are you highlight the icon of a file and pressing `ctrl-c`, or are you editing the filename and copying that instead? Where to you try to paste it in RStudio: the R console, a file-tab, or ...?

Comment: @r2evans I am not changing the file name, I am highlighting the file in file explorer and pressing ctrl-c, then trying to paste into the script editor. I will update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Honestly, I would never have tried that, it's completely out of my workflow/habit-patterns. Looks like you're a few months behind: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/4572 :-)

Comment: @r2evans Thanks! Don't know why I couldn't find that issue...

Comment: Yeah, sometimes GitHub is a little wonky when it comes to best search techniques in issues, especially because the second phase of searching is either (1) reading all content of each issue, or (2) trusting that the title is well-written (often not a safe assumption). In this case, it was simply `is:issue is:open paste`, and the 8th one down had a title of *"Paste a file from Windows Explorer"*, about as good a match as I hoped for. :-)